# i/0 error dev sr0 sector al iniciar cualquier distribucion que tengo

Tags: linux, windows

Tengo un problema, a la hora de iniciar y mostrarme la pantalla de arranque donde están las opciones para entrar a la bios. Al seleccionar un arranque se queda congelado. Sin embargo si saco los periféricos y reinicio se inicia normalmente. Ahora cuando se inicia por defecto me sale el siguiente error i/0 error dev sr0 sector

Y no logra iniciar. Sin embargo para seleccionar la otra distribución que tengo en mi grub como no logra reconocer mouse y teclado, al iniciar tengo que conectarlas cuando están en la pestaña del grub y seleccionar rapidamente otra distro. En este caso ubuntu sale el mismo mensaje e inicia con normalidad.  ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?, ¿Es problema del disco?

Comment: Pareciera que sí. Intenta bootear desde un dispositivo diferente como un Live CD o Live USB.

Comment: sacando todos los perifericos arranca , luego que inicia recien puedo conectar el mouse y teclado , sino hago eso no arranca, y tratando de bootear desde usb se queda igual

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que grub esté mal configurado, y al arrancar busque el kernel en el cd-rom (Por lo general, los sistemas linux ubican el cd-rom en /sr0, el HDD en sda y los usb en sdb). Mi recomendación es que, ya que te deja arrancar ubuntu, ejecutes `sudo update-grub` para que actualize el cargador grub.

Respecto al bloqueo de BIOS: Cuando conectamos un pendrive, cd-rom u otro dispositivo de almacenamiento, algunas (sobre todo las antiguas) BIOS buscan en ellos un cargador de arranque o un sistema operativo. Esto no pasa en las UEFI, porque ya arrancan directamente sin comprobar nada.
Intenta desactivar el arranque de usb/cd-rom (Es muy probable que si tu BIOS es antigua no puedas hacerlo sin apagar los USB/lectores de CD-ROM, impidiéndote usar los periféricos como ya comentas).
Suerte! :)

P.D: ¿Que modelo de BIOS tienes? A lo mejor te puedo ayudar a configurarla ;)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes entrar en la BIOS y comprobar en qué orden intenta acceder al CD-ROM, por que sr0 es el dispositivo SCSI que normalmente se asocia a los CD-ROM; es posible que esté intentando acceder a quién sabe qué pensando que es un CD y lo mejor sería que arranque directamente desde disco.

En la BIOS también puedes ver qué opciones tienen marcadas los USB, hay ciertos parámetros que pueden no ser compatibles con los periféricos que estés usando, normalmente tener activadas las funciones tipo "legacy" suele hacer que todo funcione.

Comment: nopuedo entrar pues la primera pestaña que me aparece si tengo conectado algun periferico no lo reconoce , luego que pasa la pestaña inicial en la que esta la bios recien puedo conectar los perifericos

Answer (score 0):

Casi seguro que es un problema del grub. Como dice Pablo, arranca tu Ubuntu y ejecuta:

```
sudo update-grub
```